# Does Apple tailor iOS software in any way for specific regions?

Tags: ios, internationalization, language

If I buy an iPad or iPhone in Saudi Arabia, for instance, from a Saudi carrier, will the UI have been tailored in any way? I am thinking specifically of removing references to Israel, for example, in lists of countries, supported regional formats, etc.

Comment: Well, some companies do perform carrier customization via special configuration files/parameters, so I was wondering if iOS/Apple does the same thing. If specific apps can be removed as mentioned by TomG below (Facetime), then it is probably not outside the realm of possibility to do other customizations. That is not to say it is being done.

Comment: Yes, and that was also what I was referring to. That type of filtering can be done. I am wondering if Apple is doing it in any market.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought you were referring specifically to [feature limitations in specific countries](http://www.apple.com/uk/ios/feature-availability/).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge so far the only differences in iOS that depend on the country are a) Facetime is omitted at governmental request in certain countries, and b) at present, 10-key/T9 screen keyboards are only available on devices bought in China and Korea.